# Performing a Scan or Query on dynamoDB (AWS) for iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, swift3, amazon-dynamodb, xcode8

I'm using Xcode Version 8.2.1, swift3 and I'm using the AWS mobile hub to connect to dynamoDB. I can successfully store and retrieve items from the database using dynamoDBObjectMapper.save and dynamoDBObjectMapper.load but I'm getting an error when I try to retrieve items using the query or scan command.

```
dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan(Books.self, expression: scanExpression).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask<AnyObject>!) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error as? NSError {
            print("The request failed. Error: \(error)")
        } else if let paginatedOutput = task.result {
            for book in paginatedOutput.items as! Books {
                // Do something with book.
            }
        }

        return ()

    })
```

The error is as follows: Cannot invoke 'continueWith' with an argument list of type '(block: (AWSTask!) -> Any?)'

The project fails to compile. How can I fix this problem? Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The method `scan` returns an `AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>` object.
   Please use the correct parameter in the block's argument list
2. The typecast should be to an array not the element type

   ```
   objectMapper.scan(Book.self, expression: scanExpression).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>!) -> Any? in
       if let error = task.error as? NSError {
           print("The request failed. Error: \(error)")
       } else if let paginatedOutput = task.result {
           for book in paginatedOutput.items as! [Book] {
               // Do something with book.
           }
       }

       return ()

   })
   ```

Comment: Thank you donkon, it makes sense! All working well now ;)